# Interesting thus complex recursive Big-O Calculation - Specific examples

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am totally a beginner learning a subject called Algorithms and Data Structures and got to the part about Big-O Notation. I have read many different materials writing about this but most of them just show examples of calculation of simple cases.

The assignment for this topic has some really interesting complex examples with recursion calling each other and for loops, while loops, etc...which I could not figure out and need help on calculating. I really appreciate any help and explanation, to understand deeply about this.

Also:
Ex No.3: I don't understand what the meaning of return "0xCAFE + 0xBABE + s"? I couldn't see it appear anywhere in the method, really strange to me.

Ex No.4: At first I thought these are different examples but I notice in method g has a call for method f so it should be in one example, is my assumption correct?

1.

```
long c(int x) {
    if (x <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        long s = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            s = s + c(x - 1);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

2.

```
long d(int x) {
    long s = -x * x;
    while (s <= x * x * x) {
        s++;
    }
    for (long i = s * x; i > 0; i--) {
        s--;
    }
    return s;
}
```

3.

```
double e(long x, long y) {
    double s = 0_0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i *= 2) {
        for (double j = x; j >= 1; j /= 3) {
            for (int k = 0; k < y; k += 4) {
                s++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0xCAFE + 0xBABE + s;
}
```

4.Calculate each f & g

```
long f(int x, int y) {
    if (x <= 0) {
        return y;
    } else {
        return f(x - 1, 2 * y);
    }
}

double g(int x, int y) {
    double s = 0.0D;
    for (long i = f(x, y); i >= 0; i--) {
        s++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

5.

```
char h(int x) {
    char h = 'h';
    for (long i = h; i-- > ++i; x--) {
        h++;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: what is the question ? do you want people to do your homework ?

Comment: To answer the "bonus" questions, 3) the return value has nothing to do with the time complexity in this case - can you see why? 4) depends on what you mean by "example" - if you meant a single function then I don't see how it can be expressed so succinctly.

Comment: So sorry but I'm just trying to understand the problem, after searching and reading for days, I hasn't found yet any materials explaining further for those with complex structures. If you have any link which also give complex examples and explain their way to calculate it, please leave a comment I will very appreciate that also.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O is just a way to measure the Runtime it takes for algorithms to complete. 
You should look at the base of how to understand this before you try to understand these examples because they're rather complex.

A small example: O(n)

```
public void o(int n, int i) {
    if (i == n)
       return;

    o(n, i++);
}
```

This resembles a for loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

In example 3:

```
return 0xCAFE + 0xBABE + s;
```

Is arbitrary, it looks like it doesn't represent anything and 's' will be the big O value for the methods complexity through its loops,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i *= 2) { // BigO = 2 ^ i
    for (double j = x; j >= 1; j /= 3) {  // BigO = (2 ^i) / 3
        for (int k = 0; k < y; k += 4) {  //BigO = y / 4
```